# Can "correct" be used in the sense of "decent" in "My day was correct/decent"?

Tags: word-meaning, spoken-english, synonyms, french

After a discussion with a French native speaker, I am asking here:

Can the sentence "My day was correct" be used synonymously with "My day was decent" when answering to "How was your day?".

For context: The disagreement stems from the fact that the French "correct" can be translated both to the English "correct" and "decent", depending on the meaning.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can check the different definitions of "correct" in a dictionary to see if one matches, and, less reliably, you can look up the applicable definition of "decent" in a dictionary that lists synonyms and see if "correct" is there (some dictionaries list per-definition synonyms).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'Decent' meaning 'conforming with generally accepted standards of respectable or moral behaviour' is what the French 'correct' means. A decent person in this sense does not, for example, walk around naked, or urinate, in public.

'Decent' meaning 'acceptable, good, pleasant', etc is **not** equivalent to the French 'correct', so it would not be idiomatic or normal English to say 'I had a correct day' when you mean e.g. you had a pleasant lunch, the sun shone, you sold lots of shoes in your shop, etc. You had a decent day. Also 'decent' used in this way is slightly informal.

Comment: If your day was only 'decent' it wasn't as good as a 'nice, enjoyable, pleasant' day. A native speaker might say "My day was OK".

Comment: @KateBunting - maybe I'm using, without realising, British understatement. I might call a day in which I married the heiress to a brewery and won the lottery a decent day.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I always thought of decent as the middle point on the good-to-bad scale. If you told me that was a decent day, I would think the brewery failing and the tax bill for the lotto came before the winnings.

Comment: @coteyr - if the brewery failed, I'd help to dispose of the remaining stock (I won't say 'liquidate'), and we don't pay tax on lotto wins in the UK.

Comment: YMMV, but I (BrE speaker) would consider "decent" to be somewhere between "OK" and "good".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'd call that a sarcastic use of the word, you're deliberately downplaying how great it was.

Comment: To my AmE ear, if someone said their day was "Decent", I would think they meant "it wasn't a great day, but at least it could have been worse"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that would be a bad day, as if you had realised that you were going to win the lottery there would have been no need to marry the heiress!

Comment: @tgdavies - but if I genuinel lover her, and she loves me?

Comment: I recently heard a BBC radio programme about misunderstandings between British and Germans working in each others' countries. A German came to the UK and when his boss said a project he carried out had a 'decent' result, he felt underpraised. After 15 years in London, he had switched, he said, and his fellow Germans felt the same resentment about things he said. he said he now found them boastful, and called them 'Herr Doktors'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Then you wouldn't have mentioned that her family owned a brewery :-)

Comment: @Barmar - maybe you misunderstand. I'm not talking about sarcasm or 'deliberate' underplaying of something. It's _how we speak_. Conversation is rarely context-free, anyhow. A year's work that led to the team landing a billion-dollar contract and six-figure bonuses all round is quite a decent result. We just don't jump up and down, wave our arms about and shout a lot about things.

Comment: I am reminded of the joke, told at the time, of a 'theatrical type' (i.e. male homosexual) who served in the trenches on the Western Front during World War 1. Afterwards, he was asked what it was like. 'My _dear!_' he exclaimed. 'The _noise!_ And the _people!_'

Answer (score 1):

If someone says their day was decent in Irish English, it means it was not bad. We cannot say, "my day was correct."

Comment: It isn't true to say we cannot.  Simply that we do not.

Comment: @Chenmunka - in (fairly) informal speech, 'cannot say' can be interpreted to mean  'cannot say and be considered to be speaking normal English'. For example _You cannot say 'three apples is on the table'_ or _You cannot say 'He told I to go away'_, or _You cannot say 'Me am hungry'_.

Answer (score 1):

No, the sentence *"My day was correct."* would sound quite strange to a native English speaker's ears.

However, *"My day was alright."* would be a perfectly normal/idiomatic response.*

* (In American English at least.)